# how to display name of a linked list using only the first three words of a person's name as an initial

Tags: c, linked-list

How to use initials to search for a person's name in a linked list with the same initials? I've used strstr but it still won't work.

```
void searchStudent(char searchName[]){
    curr = head;
    int i = 1;
    
    while(curr->next != NULL && strstr(curr->name, searchName) != 0){ 
        curr = curr->next;
    } 
    if (curr->next == NULL){
        printf("There no students with this initials %s\n", searchName); 
    }
    else{
        curr = head; 
        while(curr->next != NULL){
            if(strstr(curr->name, searchName) == 0){
                printf("Student #%d\n", i); 
                printf("Name    : %s\n", curr->name);
                printf("Student Number      : %s\n", curr->number );
                printf("------------------------------------\n"); 
                i++;  
                curr = curr->next;
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

The output of that coding is always this "There no students with this initials %s\n "

Comment: Please improve your example code to be self-contained.  This means include a main and initial your tree with minimal data that demonstrate problem.  Remove code that is not relevant to demonstrate the issue, for example, last 3 print statements.

Comment: Have you mixed up `strstr` and `strcmp`? The first function searches for a substring in a string and returns a pointer to it or null if the substring can't be found. The second categorizes a string as being smaller than, equal to or greater than another string. When there is a hit, `strstr` returns non-null and `strstr` returns 0.

Comment: Support @AllanWind , to improve your question, more specific suggestions are:  1. explain briefly to the data structure of your linked list , i.e curr. 2. since this is function, the output depends on how did you call it, so you should post the outer caller context to say it is how did you call it.

Answer (score 1):

`strstr()` returns NULL when a match was *not* found, so you probably want to change:

```
curr = head;
...
while(curr->next != NULL && strstr(curr->name, searchName) != 0){
...
if (curr->next == NULL){
    printf("There no students with this initials %s\n", searchName); 
}
```

to:

```
for(curr = head; curr && !strstr(curr->name, searchName); curr = curr->next, i++);
if(!curr) {
   printf("There no students with this initials %s\n", searchName); 
}
```

This also fixes, what is probably a defect, that your original code didn't look at the last node.

Your code relies on global variables.  Suggest you refactor your function to accept the head variable as an argument.

Comment: will this code works to search through multiple data within the linked lists?

Comment: It will search through all nodes till it finds a match.

Comment: I just tried your code. There is no problem if the data exists but if the data doesn't exist, it will not print "There no students with this initials %s\n" I tried debugging it but the if will not even enter the if statement

Comment: I suggest you update the question with your current code.  The loop exits when the loop condition is false.  !(curr & !strstr) == !curr || strstr().  !curr is in case where we didn't find the value which is exactly what we check for in the following if condition.  You said it works when the element in found which the strstr() case you said worked.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is probably the correct one, but what I'd suggest here is to put your `printf` statements and debugging code in the loop itself, so you can see what's going on and it will be easier to catch the mistake, rather than having a pretty complex and opaque `while` loop where you can't really tell what's going on (beyond if it 'works' or not).

For example:

```
for(curr=head; node!=NULL; curr=curr->next) {
    printf("StrStr output: %s", strstr(curr->name, searchName)); 
    printf("Student #%d\n", i); 
    printf("Name    : %s\n", curr->name);
    printf("Student Number      : %s\n", curr->number );
}
```

Now you can see all the printed students and then what the `strstr` returns. From that it should be pretty easy to fix your program.
Now, for example, you'll be able to see if the `strstr()` returns `0` or `-1` or `NULL` or whatever it is (you'll find out) when you insert the print statements and be able to easily fix your code.

Comment: As author of the *other answer* just wanted to say that I like the suggestion :-)

Comment: @AllanWind well thank you! I'm a beginner in C so just started to ask/answer some questions.

Comment: Suggest the enhancement to move the statements to a function, and call the function here if the DEBUG is defined `#ifdef DEBUG\nprint_node(curr)#endif` then `#define DEBUG 1` at the top.  i is not updated so either do or comment that print line out.  In your loop change `node` to `curr`.  Your loop currently iterates through all elements, if that is what you intend, reset curr= later on to head after the loop to document that or add something in the condition to break the loop when element is found.